# Understanding Markov Chains in terms of Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, probability, markov-chains

In [a lecture on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AJPs3gvNlY&feature=player_detailpage#t=2011), a professor said Markov Chains could be simplified to `Start(S) * Transition Matrix(Q)^State#`

I'm trying to replicate this using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
S = np.zeros(shape=(1,2))
Q = np.zeros(shape=(2,2))

#starting state
S[0] = [.2,.8]

#transition matrix
Q[0] = [.9, .1]
Q[1] = [.7, .3]
```

If I do `print S.dot(Q).dot(Q)`, it gives me `[[0.848  0.152]]` which appears to be the correct answer (two steps into the future).

However, this doesn't exactly seem the same as `SQ^x`, so I tried `print S.dot(np.power(Q,2))`, but that gives me `[[0.554  0.074]]`. Where am I going wrong, or what don't I understand here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expressions `S.dot(Q).dot(Q)` and `S.dot(np.power(Q,2))` are not the same thing. The first is the behaviour you desire, while `S.dot(np.power(Q,2))` raises each element in `Q` to the second power. Documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html).

For a more compact notation than repeatedly chaining `.dot(Q)`, use:

```
S.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(Q,n))
```

where `n` is the desired power.

Answer (score 4):

Stick with dot.
`np.power` or `*` operator is elementwise multiplication. Look at:

```
print Q.dot(Q)
```

prints:

```
[[ 0.88  0.12]
 [ 0.84  0.16]]
```

which is what I get by hand.
Whereas,

```
print np.power(Q, 2)
print Q * Q
```

both print:

```
[[ 0.81  0.01]
 [ 0.49  0.09]]
```

So `S.dot(Q).dot(Q)` is correct.